# Trace java app in netbeans and search for a substring in all the variables or returned variables and stop tracing when it appears

Tags: java, debugging, maven, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is there a way to tell netbeans debugger or any other ide/debugger trace a java application step by step, searching for a specific substring in all the variables each step, and stop and show the line where the substring appeared and in which variable it appeared? Or, maybe, search only for the strings that appear in objects returned by any method?

Maybe there's other way do it?

I'm debugging a java app acquired from a freelancer I cannot get in touch with. I'm not familiar with java, but I already fixed (with the help of netbeans debugger and common sense) some bugs I found in this app.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not exactly what you need (and I doubt something like that exists - you can set conditional breakpoints but that doesn't work globally) - you could use [Byteman](http://www.jboss.org/byteman) project which is supposed to inspect and also inject code into your running Java applications. You define set of rules which than will be applied to your running code - hence when the condition (like your substring) is satisfied, you can inject `System.out.println();` and see contents of variables in methods and classes.

Basic tutorial can be found [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ABytemanTutorial) - also look into comments, there is an example of conditional inserting.